# Secure API keys

Tags: api, security, cryptography

I have created an API and I would like to allow other developers to get the information from it. So the idea is to generate and assign API keys to everyone that wants to query our information. With API keys I can limit the daily requests and secure my data.

The thing is, I am concerned about the security aspect of it. Since the API key is going to be sent to our server (via GET/POST etc)?

I am looking for the best solution to handle this problem. 

The solution in my mind is to use Asymmetric Cryptography to handle this.
Is it the right way to handle this? If not what is the best way.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Assymetric cryptography to encrypt the communication channel (in this case use SSL) or to sign requests using the private key of the client and validate with the public?

Comment: Just use TLS for the transmission. Everything you do will not be secure enough.